# google app script how to get date in string date(spread sheet)

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to compare the date that was created in the spreadsheet with a specific date.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var spreaddate = ss.getSheetByName("sheet123").getRange("B2").getValue();
//--> Thu Dec 12 00:00:00 GMT+09:00 2019
var comparedate = new date(yyyy-mm-dd)//somting like this
if(spreaddate > comparedate){
do something
}
```

The spreaddate is not recognized as a date.
Even if I try to convert it to a date, it's hard because it's written in letters, not numbers like Thu Dec.
What should I do?

Comment: If the output of `spreaddate` is "Thu Dec 12 00:00:00 GMT+09:00 2019", then it's probably a date. Your declaration of `comparedate` looks wrong, though. What's the exact error you're receiving?

Comment: Diego It's good to try again.
I made a wrong date for the comparison.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're not correctly  defining your `comparedate`. You need to use a capital 'D' [`new Date()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).